# Can the zoneRedundant property be used with app service plan using bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to specify the property for zone redundancy with an app service plan definition using Bicep. I am using Visual Studio Code. Intellisense says this property is not supported. Has anyone encountered this issue, and if so, how did you get around it?

Comment: Could you please add your bicep flie ? Which version are you using ? the latest version seems to have the property tho: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-03-01/serverfarms?tabs=bicep.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded to the latest version and the error message went away. Thank you.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if working for you please :-) ?

Comment: Happy to. I am new to this site so I am not sure how to do that. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: You can chekc this post on how to accept: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: did that solve your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-02-01/serverfarms?tabs=bicep), I can see it is available since version `2021-02-01`. So using one of the latest versions should work:

```bicep
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-03-01' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    zoneRedundant: true
  }
}
```